# Change the return type of this PHP script to JSONArray

Tags: php, json

Thanks to @michael for assisting in getting my PHP script working. I have run into a type conflict within my Android app and I would like to adjust this script to return a `JSONArray` instead of a `JSONObject`. Here is the script.

```php
<?php

/*
* Following code will get all agencies matching the query
* Returns essential details
* An agency is identified by agency id
*/

require("DB_Link.php");

//query database for matching agency
$query = "SELECT * FROM agency WHERE City = :city";

$city = ($_GET['City']);

//Execute query
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM agency WHERE City = :city");
    $stmt->execute(array('city' => $city));
}
catch (PDOException $ex)    {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    die('Error!: ' . json_encode($ex->getMessage()));;
}

//Retrieve all found rows and add to array
$rows = $stmt->FETCHALL();


if($rows)   {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Results Available!";
    $response["agencys"] = array();

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $agency         = array();
        $agency["AgencyID"] = $row["AgencyID"];
        $agency["AgencyName"]   = $row["AgencyName"];
        $agency["Address1"] = $row["Address1"];
        $agency["City"]     = $row["City"];
        $agency["State"]    = $row["State"];
        $agency["Zip"]      = $row["Zip"];
        $agency["Lat"]      = $row["Lat"];
        $agency["Lng"]      = $row["Lng"];

        //update response JSON data
        array_push($response["agencys"], $agency);
    }

    //Echo JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);

} else  {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Agency found!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean? `json` returned is a string and not an `object` or an `array`. You should probably look at your java code and how it parses that response and not the `php` part

Comment: I don't see anything to do with Java, Android or MySQL.

Comment: With a JSON return if it starts with a { it is a JSONObject in Java/Android. When the return starts with a [ it is seen as a JSONArray. If it begins with any other character it is seen as a string by Java. I have found plenty of other scripts that return a JSONArray. I'm just not sure how to change this script to do the same.

Comment: Assuming you just want an array with one element (your object): `echo json_encode(array($response));`

Comment: Here is a sample of the return from this script {"success":1,"message":"Results Available!","agencys":[{"AgencyID":"2579","AgencyName":"name","Address1":"street","City":"city","State":"NY","Zip":"14226","Lat":"0.000000","Lng":"0.000000"}]}    And this is what I would like to get back from the PHP     [{"AgencyID":"2579","AgencyName":"name","Address1":"street","City":"city","State":"NY","Zip":"14226","Lat":"0.000000","Lng":"0.000000"}]

Answer (score 1):

Just to cover this for other people looking later and to explain why this happens. When PHP runs the json_encode function arrays that are key value pairs are treated as objects and if you would like them returned as an array of objects they will need to be wrapped in another array.

```
json_encode(array("key" => "value"));
```

Output:

```
{"key":"value"}
```

To turn it into an array...

```
json_encode(array(array("key" => "value")));
```

Output:

```
[{"key":"value"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. PHP is relatively new for me. I have used it before, but mainly for contact forms on a website. This is the first time I have used it to retrieve data from a remote database.

Comment: @IrishCarBomb No problem at all glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around here is what I what I came up with. Changing my original script to the following returns results in the format I was looking for.

[{"AgencyID":"2579","AgencyName":"name","Address1":"street","City":"city","State‌​":"NY","Zip":"14226","Lat":"0.000000","Lng":"0.000000"}]

```
<?php



/*

* Following code will get all agencies matching the query

* Returns essential details

* An agency is identified by agency id

*/



require("DB_Link.php");



//query database for matching agency

$query = "SELECT * FROM agency WHERE City = :city";



$city = ($_GET['City']);



//Execute query

try {

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT AgencyID, AgencyName, Address1, City, State, Zip, Lat, Lng FROM agency WHERE City = :city");

    $stmt->execute(array('city' => $city));

}

catch (PDOException $ex)    {

    $response["success"] = 0;

    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";

    die('Error!: ' . json_encode($ex->getMessage()));;

}



//Retrieve all found rows and add to array

$result = $stmt->FETCHALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($result);


?>
```